# Unmarshal JSON preserving null values

Tags: json, mongodb, go

My scenario is the follow:

I have a server/worker made with Go. In a background routine, the server receives messages in JSON format, and then updates a MongoDB database with this data.

One of the problems is, some of the MongoDB data types, such as ObjectId and Date, are often converted to string when they must be represented as JSON, so before inserting that data into the database, I unmarshall that JSON in a structure, and then send that structure to the MongoDB driver. The structure implements methods such as `UnmarshalJSON` and `MarshalBSONValue`, so their data types are preserved.

Great, everything is solved. But by using structures I get another problem, supposing I have the following structure:

```
type Integers struct {
    Foo *int `json:"foo" bson:"foo"`
    Bar *int `json:"bar" bson:"foo"`
    Baz *int `json:"baz" bson:"foo"`
}
```

And then i receive the following JSON:

```
{"foo": 0, "bar": null}
```

With this JSON, I should be updating my database with `foo = 0`, `bar = null`, and ignore `baz`. However, if I unmarshall this JSON in my structure, I'll have the equivalent of:

```
Integers{
    Foo: 1,
    Bar: nil,
    Baz: nil,
}
```

But with this I can't tell if I received `bar` and `baz`, or they just defaulted to `nil`, so I can't properly update the database.

---

**How I believe it could be solved:**

By having the following structure:

```
type Integers struct {
    Foo SmartassInt `json:"foo,omitempty" bson:"foo,omitempty"`
    Bar SmartassInt `json:"bar,omitempty" bson:"bar,omitempty"`
    Baz SmartassInt `json:"baz,omitempty" bson:"baz,omitempty"`
}
```

I would be able to differentiate between a `null`, and a non-received value, as the following example:

```
var foo int = 0
var fooPointer *int = &foo
var barPointer *int = nil

integers := Integers{
    Foo: &fooPointer,
    Bar: &barPointer,
    Baz: nil,
}
```

With this structure, `baz` will not be inserted in the database, as its value is `nil`, and `nil` is ignored thanks to the flag `omitempty`. `bar` however is not `nil`, but it points to `nil`, which is different from being empty, so it's properly inserted as `null` in the database.

But how can I achieve this initialization with with the received JSON?

The standard JSON unmarshaller would initialize both `bar` and `baz` as `nil`.

Implementing my own marshaller methods, such as

```
type NullableInt **int

func (i NullableInt) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {

}

func (i NullableInt) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {

}
```

Is not possible either, since `NullableInt` is a pointer, and I can't implement methods on pointers.

So, which approach could I use to solve this problem?

Comment: You might be better off working with a `map[string]interface{}` instead of a struct if you really need to differentiate between nonexistent fields and fields with nil values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the decode side, you can write a custom unmarshaler for a custom type:

```
type MaybeInt struct {
    Present bool
    Null    bool
    Value   int64
}

func (m *MaybeInt) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    s := string(data)
    m.Present = true
    if s == "null" {
        m.Null = true
        return nil
    }
    v, err := strconv.ParseInt(s, 10, 64)
    m.Value = v
    return err
}
```

Complete example [here](https://play.golang.org/p/WelVw-19EVN).  Unfortunately, this doesn't work on the encode side: there is no way for the `MarshalJSON` handler to indicate that the field is empty.  The obvious way would be to return `nil, nil` from a Marshaler, but that doesn't work.  Neither does returning `[]byte{}, nil`.

You might suppose: well, let's use a pointer, and set it to `nil` when we want to say that the field should be omitted.  This works on the *decode* side, but now the encode side fails, because the encoder sees the literal `null` and doesn't call our encoder at all!

Ultimately, we can combine both techniques: read into `MaybeInt`, encode (write) from `*MaybeInt`.  We'll need parallel struct types.  We can *set* the output type based on the input type.  I don't claim this to be *pretty*, and the `reflect` code in it is terrible (you can also see all my debug tracery), but this actually seems to work: [Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/pcss1XY2lWD).  In practice, instead of using `reflect`, you might just write a function for each case of a "maybe" value.